# Integrating php and .net applications with wordpress

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

the company I work for have a pure HTML website and now they want to migrate it to wordpress, that's ok, the problem is that they have many web applications written in PHP and .net. what is the best approach to integrate both kind of applications with wordpress??

I don't want to use iframes to embeed existing applications on the wordpress site.

I think that I'll need to convert the PHP applications to wordpress plugins so I can write a shortcode for the app and write it on a wordpress page/post and it will display ok, is this approach ok?

And for .net applications, I have no idea how to do it, the .net applications are on another server (Windows Server) and the wordpress site is on a Linux Server.

Can someone give me some ideas about best practices for doing this integration?

Thank you so much

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do and what you mean by integrate.

Comment: And how many custom code and/or content there is. If it is not too much you could just spend a few hours copy/paste the content and rewrite the code from scratch.

Comment: @VDWWD this is really a lot of code, rewriting from scratch is not a good idea, I will never finish it hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that I'll need to convert the PHP applications to wordpress
>   plugins so I can write a shortcode for the app and write it on a
>   wordpress page/post and it will display ok, is this approach ok?

You dont need create a plugin for this, a shortcode is just a function call in WP

> And for .net applications, I have no idea how to do it, the .net
>   applications are on another server (Windows Server) and the wordpress
>   site is on a Linux Server.

The dirty way without iframe:

curl the net app in a wp shortcode, load dom, select the dom parts you need...

The cleaner way:

Create an api interface (SOAP, REST) on the .net side.

Comment: So, with a simple shortcode I can render the full app inside a wordpress page or post? Or I am understading wrong?

Comment: You understanding it wrong. Call the .net app via curl, then parse the DOM with PHP (http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php). Now you can select the requirement parts of the called website inside of the Document Object Model and echo it via PHP

Comment: OK, I will try this solution and I will tell you what  happened